# Postman returning <pre>Cannot GET /usuario</pre>

Tags: javascript, token

I'm following a Node.js course with refresh tokens and in some part of the code I started getting this error and I couldn't figure out what might be causing it.
I followed the course and my requests always worked well, but there was a class where the tutor needed to modify some parts of the code. I grabbed the files from GitHub to see what changed and modified my code as well. But from then on my postman requests didn't work anymore.

On Postman I have this error message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /usuario</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

In my VS Code terminal the API is working normally.
[image]

My server.js file is

```
require('dotenv').config()

const app = require('./app');
const port = 3000;
require('./')
require('./database');
require('./redis/blocklist');

const routes = require('./rotas');
routes(app);

app.listen(port, () => console.log("A API está conectada!"))
```

My routes.js code is

```
const posts = require('./src/posts');
const usuarios = require('./src/usuarios');

module.exports = app => {
    posts.rotas(app);
    usuarios.rotas(app);
};
```

My user-routes.js code is

```
const usuariosControlador = require('./usuarios-controlador');
const middlewaresAutenticacao = require('./middlewares-autenticacao');


module.exports = (app) => {
    app.route('/usuario/login')
    app.post(middlewaresAutenticacao.local, usuariosControlador.login);

    app.route('/usuario/logout')
    app.get(middlewaresAutenticacao.bearer, usuariosControlador.logout);

    app.route('/usuario')
    app.post(usuariosControlador.adiciona)
    app.get(usuariosControlador.lista);

    app.route('/usuario/:id')
    app.delete(middlewaresAutenticacao.bearer, usuariosControlador.deleta);
};
```

My code is on GitHub: https://github.com/Stephani0106/Seguranca-com-NodeJS

And my tutor's code is: https://github.com/alura-cursos/blog-do-codigo-2

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example, instead of your whole code base.

Comment: already updated

Comment: You're misusing the `app.route()` method. I suggest you look closely at [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route). TL;DR you need to remove the `app` prefix from `.post`, `.get`, etc when you're using them after `app.route()`... `app.route("/usuario").post(...).get(...)`. **Voting to close as a TYPO**